# Pingfederate with Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, pingfederate

I am trying to get a Tomcat application front-ended by Apache integrate with Pingfederate. Its agent based integration and I have used Apache Integration Kit 3.0. I am bale to get the agent work in the end I am getting this error:

```
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Entering the Headers Fixup handler
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info]   Client's host is not whitelisted - Agent is enabled
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info]   AuthType is "PFApacheAgent" - Agent is enabled
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Cleaning up headers with prefix "HPPF_AUTH_"...
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Entering the Content handler
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info]   Client's host is not whitelisted - Agent is enabled
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info]   AuthType is "PFApacheAgent" - Agent is enabled
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Checking whether the request implies to fill out and return the start page...
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] The request URL does not match the configured start page filter
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] The request does not imply to fill out and return the start page
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Filtering by URI is disabled - anonymous filters are not configured
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] The URI of GET request does not match the filter
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] The requested resource is not protected - no need to validate session
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Granting access to the requested resource
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Returning DECLINED to let Apache take its default actions for the modified request
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Exiting the Content handler
[Tue Aug 05 03:01:59 2014] [info] Returning HTTP code -1 (DECLINED)
```

Comment: What does your mod_pf.conf look like?

Comment: Here is how my mod_pf.conf looks like:

Comment: Can you just modify the question to include the mod_pf.conf, please? Thanks!